# Serre's Trick for flatness of a morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading some exercises on abelian varieties and I came across the following claim:

> > **Claim (Serre's Trick):** Let $X,Y,S$ be schemes and suppose that $X \times_S Y$ is flat over $S$. If $X(S) \neq \emptyset$ then $Y$ is flat over $S$.

Evidently to prove the claim we may reduce to the case where $X = \operatorname{Spec} C$, $S = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y= \operatorname{Spec} B$ where $A,B,C$ are local rings and the maps $A \to B$, $A \to C$ are local homomorphisms.

Let $\mathfrak{m}_A, \mathfrak{m}_B$ and $\mathfrak{m}_C$ be the maximal ideals of $A,B,C$ respectively.

> > (**) Suppose for the moment that the tensor product $B \otimes_A C$ contains a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ that contracts simultaneously to $\mathfrak{m}_A$ and $\mathfrak{m}_B$.

By localizing at $\mathfrak{m}$, we may assume that $B \otimes_A C$ is local, and the composition
$$A \to B \to B \otimes_A C$$
is faithfully flat (flat + local homomorphism implies faithfully flat).

With this I think we can prove that $B$ is flat over $A$ as follows. Let
$M \to N$ be an injection of $A$-modules. Let $K$ be the kernel of the map
$M \otimes_A B \to N \otimes_A B$. Tensoring with $C$, we get that 
$$K \otimes_A C  = 0$$

using flatness of $B \otimes_A C$ over $A$. Now tensor with $B$ to get
$$ K \otimes_A (C \otimes_A B) = 0$$
and conclude that $K= 0$ by faithful flatness.

> > **My question is:** A necessary condition for (**) to be true is that the product $B \otimes_A C$ is not zero. How can I get this just from the fact that there is a map $C \to A$? Indeed the example
> >     $$ \Bbb{Z}/2 \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q} = 0$$
> >     shows that the condition on the existence of a section is really needed.\

Edit: I was tired from travelling and stupidly concluded that $-\otimes_A C$ was injective.

Comment: Why $K\otimes_AC=0$?

Comment: For local homomorphisms $A \to B$, $A \to C$, you have $B\otimes_AC=0$. Moreover, there always exists a prime ideal of $B\otimes_AC$ contracting in $B$ and $C$ to their maximal ideals. The second claim is EGA I Springer edition, Corollaire 3.2.7.1.(i) (the proof is immediate) and the first follows from the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proof of the 'claim':

Since $X(S)\neq \emptyset$, you have a map $S \to X$ and then a factorization of the identity map of $Y$: $Y \to Y\times_SS \to Y\times_SX \to Y$. Since $Y\times_SX$ is flat, so is $Y$.

Comment: I wrote this down earlier but didn't see how to conclude. I think I do now, but is there some general principle here that I should recognize?

Comment: $Y$ is a retract of $Y\times_SX$. In terms of rings, $S$= Spec $A$, $B$= Spec $Y$, etc., $B$ is a direct summand of the flat A-module $B\otimes_AC$.

Comment: That's even better. Thanks! I was so focused on base change and composition.

Comment: @A.G Beautiful proof!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:C\rightarrow A$ be a  map (which is non zero, I assume you have units in the ring involved), you have a non zero $A$-bilinear map
$h:C\times B\rightarrow B$ defined by $h(c,b)=f(c)b$, by the universal property of the tensor product, $h$ factors by a map $\bar h:C\otimes_AB\rightarrow B$, henceforth, $C\otimes_AB$ is not trivial.